# Tests stall for no obvious reason

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I have been happily unit testing in Laravel 9 for the last few days and am gradually getting the hang of how to write tests for various circumstances. I ran many tests and was learning a lot when suddenly, for no obvious reason, the php artisan test command stopped working properly. Starting at about 11am today, the very first test in the very first test case executes successfully and then the whole thing just stalls: no other tests are attempted. There are no error messages and waiting prolonged periods doesn't result in the tests restarting on their own.

I've tried doing a CTRL-C to break out of the test and then started again. Same result. I've tried closing the terminal window, opening another and running php artisan test again. I've tried using a different terminal window outside of VS Code altogether. Same result. I've tried closing and re-opening VS Code. Same result. I've even rebooted the computer (I'm running Windows 10) but am getting exactly the same result. I just can't get beyond the first test in the first test case.

I can't think of anything else to try. The second test case has been run successfully many times so I can't believe it is the problem. Can anyone suggest what the problem might be and how I can get past it?

I'm using PHPUnit 9.x.

```
UPDATE
```

As per Matias' suggestion, I ran `php artisan test -vvv` on my test suite. (I also renamed all of the files in the Unit Test directory so that they wouldn't run, except for the two ExampleTest test cases that were generated by Laravel, one for feature testing and one for unit testing.) The very long stacktrace pointed to an inability of the tests to connect to my local MySQL database. That made sense because I hadn't restarted XAMPP after the reboot. (Then again, I didn't see the urgency because none of the code I was testing used the database; they dealt with strings, arrays and collections.) I restarted XAMPP, including Apache and MySQL. Now, all tests the ExampleTest test cases completed. I renamed my Helper2Txxx.php to Helper2Test.php and assumed it would run smoothly now. Unfortunately, that *didn't* happen. Helper2Text.php don't run at all: the testing stopped as soon as the ExampleTest had finished.

I commented out all but the most trivial test in Helper2Test and it ran successfully. I uncommented a few tests at a time until I found the one that made all of the test cycle stop and that (unsurprisingly) turned out to be the last one I had written. Further investigation revealed that a small function I'd written to help with the testing was running into a memory error:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 264257536 bytes) in C:\Laravel\laragigs\tests\Unit\Helper2Test.php on line 154
```

It looks very much like I have to fix up my small function but I won't be able to do that to untilmorrow sometime. My working theory is that this memory error is the big problem that somehow breaks artisan test; somehow this kept the successful tests earlier in Helper2Test from displaying so that I had no idea where/why the test command was failing.

I'll update here as I learn more. I *think* I will be able to fix this problem myself but I'll leave the problem open in case I turn out to be wrong.

```
UPDATE 2
```

Everything is working now. I reworked my small function to accomplish the same thing via explode() instead of strtok() and it now works perfectly with no memory issues.

Thank you, Matias, for reminding me that I can get diagnostics by using the -vvv subcommand! That was the critical step in figuring out what was wrong.

Comment: I have something in mind, did you update the framework to a newer 9.x version? did you change any package? try running the command adding `-vvv` at the end so you can see a full output, maybe you can see where it is stuck

Comment: @matiaslauriti - As a matter of fact, I *did* update Laravel from 9.40.1 to 9.42.2 but that was earlier in the week and I ran many tests after that without problems. I just tried executing php artisan test -vvv but there is no additional output and the test stalls in thee same place.

Comment: @matiasluriti - I spoke too soon. There *is* additional output due to the -vvv; I just didn't wait long enough for it. I'll add this information to the original questions.

Comment: If you are using `use RefreshDatabase;` and migrations, which contain a lot of importing data, you can potentially be out of memory, especially if you are using parallel testing.